# mysql database table not response

Tags: mysql

i have use mysql database .
my problem is that 
i run a query through php that take too much time to execute. so i revert back the query to normal form. but after that my table unable to respond me .
it says
Internal Server Error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@minnies-boutique.co.uk and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

why this happened.. any suggestion please...

Comment: Judging from your questions, this isn't the first time you're asking a question without providing enough info.. you just won't learn? I'll answer why you got 500 internal server error using info you provided - **because something went wrong**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with the configuration. If you're the adminstrator check that, or tell to the administrator...